# Counting rows sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with counting rows. This is my procedure :

```
DECLARE @result table(id int,latitude float, longitude float)
Declare @z int = 1
while (@z <5) 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
@result
SELECT 
id,
loc.STPointN(@z).Lat as lat,
loc.STPointN(@z).Long as long
FROM test6
SET @z = @z+1
END
Select * from @result
ORDER BY id
```

Results:

```
ID  lat         long
1   16,71175    52,689702
1   17,008381   52,247983
2   17,228107   52,689702
2   17,008381   42,247983
2   16,71175    42,689702
```

I want to count rows with same ID, somthing like :

```
ID  lat         long       count
1   16,71175    52,689702  1
1   17,008381   52,247983  2
2   17,228107   52,689702  1
2   17,008381   42,247983  2
2   16,71175    42,689702  3
```

Any advice ? (Sorry for english)

Comment: Your initial read is unordered, so there's no guarantee that you'll get the same rows each time, or that `loc.STPointN(...)` is going get the same value of `z` each time.  It's unclear why you're reading a row-at-a-time, as opposed to a blanket `SELECT` (possibly with `CROSS APPLY`).  You also need to figure out a criteria for assigning the count, or the numbers might change each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply <kbd>[RowNumber](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2008/03/19/ranking-functions-row_number/)</kbd> window function like below

```
select
id,
lat,
long,
row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as countt
from 
yourtable
```

In the above code countt per id you get is not deterministic,if you want specific id column to have same countt,you need to order by unique value like

```
 row_number() over(partition by id order by lat) as countt
```

Comment: Note: which row gets which count (per `id`) is non-deterministic, which might be an important consideration.  At minimum, ordering by the partition does nothing, since it would be a constant value.